# How to generate basic form to edit database entry quickly?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Is there a way I can generate form in WinForms or window in WPF that can insert/edit entry in database table?
If shortcut doesn't exist can you share your experience how can I do it quickly with least effort.

I have a large project in which I have to spend lots of time modeling database and I wish to skip the visual design part and complete the application as soon as possible and then when I have time do the design right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of tools out there that can generate such a form for you imho the best is "Codesmith".

There is a pattern/code generation system baked into Visual Studio called "T4" 
([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.asp)) that is not terribly well documented but effective once you work your way through it.

If you want more control over the system, you can use various sql functions to list the tables in a db, the fields in a table (and the datatype for each field...) etc. etc. and roll your own, it really isn't that hard.

Cheers,
CEC

Comment: another great anchor resource for T4 is: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx This has LOTS of links to other resources.

Comment: I read a little about T4 before but I didn't found nice tutorial so I overlooked it now... Thanks for help I'll look into it...