# Is there a wizard to create a VS 2010 application from a database?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

I have a SQL Express database, and I'd like a very simple forms application built from it in Visual Studio 2010.  Is there some sort of wizard to make Windows Forms from an existing database?  Thanks!

EDIT: I just want something to easily create the basic CRUD forms, with the basic grid look-and-feel.  This isn't a production-quality application and I want a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into Microsoft Lightswitch.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch

> Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch is
> an IDE specifically tailored for
> creating line-of-business applications
> built on existing .NET technologies
> and Microsoft platforms. The
> applications produced are
> architecturally 3-tier: the user
> interface runs on Microsoft
> Silverlight; the logic and data-access
> tier is built on WCF RIA Services and
> Entity Framework, hosted in ASP.NET;
> and the primary data storage supports
> Microsoft SQL Server Express,
> Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft SQL
> Azure. LightSwitch also supports other
> data sources including Microsoft
> SharePoint.
>
> LightSwitch includes
> graphical designers for designing
> entities and entity relationships,
> entity queries, and UI screens.
> Business logic may be written in
> either Visual Basic or Visual C#. The
> tool can be installed as a stand-alone
> SKU or as an integrated add-in to
> Visual Studio 2010 Professional and
> higher.[50]

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488545.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Commercial solution: [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/)

Built in to Visual Studios: [T4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501678/how-to-generate-basic-form-to-edit-database-entry-quickly/5501915#5501915)